# Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, input

I'm trying to get this small movie ratings program to work properly with everything going fine until I start prompting for the ratings that the reviewer would enter. It lets me rate both acting fine but as soon as I hit the enter button to rate music is will move down to a blank line instead of prompting for the next input. The only way I to get around this seems for me to enter the value twice.

thanks

```
Console.WriteLine("Rate the following out of 5");
Console.Write("Acting > ");
acting_rating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Music > ");
Console.ReadLine();
music_rating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Cinematography > ");
Console.ReadLine();
cinematography_rating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Plot > ");
Console.ReadLine();
plot_rating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Duration > ");
Console.ReadLine();
duration_rating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

you call `Console.ReadLine();` one time too often... just remove the `Console.ReadLine();` between `Console.Write` and the `int.Parse` .

Although IF the user enters anthing wrong - like a word instead of a number - you will still get an exception... To handle that properly use a [try catch block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and/or [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).

Comment: Your first statement is wrong: That MSDN page for `Console.ReadLine` explicitly says, *"The returned string does not contain the terminating character(s)."*

Answer (score 1):

Excluding Acting, you have always two `Console.ReadLine();` i.e. :

```
Console.Write("Music > ");  // write Music > 
Console.ReadLine();         // read the user input (and throw it away)
music_rating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // read the user input again and parse it
```

Remove the single statement `Console.ReadLine();` and should be ok.